# How to create MySQL data connection in Pentaho Server

Tags: mysql, analytics, pentaho

I have installed the enterprise edition of Pentaho BA server and I need to create a MySQL Data source. For that, I have to create a new database connection. But under the Database types, it doesn't show MySQL as a database type. How to add MySQL database type for that. Can someone help here?

Comment: have you followed this? https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.1/0H0/Specify_Data_Connections_for_the_Pentaho_Server/Define_Data_Connections_for_the_Pentaho_Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that this is a community forum. It seems the fundamentals remain the same for community and enterprise editions, though.

In Pentaho community edition you will get a link below database name for adding any new databases that are not in the list of available types. You have to add the jdbc database driver jar file under "biserver-ce\tomcat\lib" and restart the server. The new database type should appear in the list.